# xlwings: how to attach matplotlib charts onto excel sheet via UDF only

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I have a question on how to add charts to excel spreadsheet through xlwings UDF. At the moment I have these code, they output the carts, however I wish to add (attach) these charts onto the spreadsheet itself, through UDF, how do I do that?

```
@xw.func
def plotstats():

    fig = plt.figure()
    print(colist, type(colist))
    print(pcgstats,type(pcgstats))
    plt.bar(colist, pcgstats.iloc[0])
    plt.title('% of Consolidated portfolios outperforming')
    fig.show()

    fig2 = plt.figure(2)
    plt.bar(colist, pcgstats.iloc[1])
    plt.title('% of individual portfolios outperforming')
    fig2.show()

    return "Plotted!"
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/matplotlib.html#full-integration-with-excel

Comment: Hi Felix, I did, it doesn't seem to work, as it outputs "#VALUE!".

Comment: Please open an issue on the GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings

Comment: thanks Felix! I will do that!